# Swift how to implement the buttons that appear at the bottom when you want to something in a lot of apps

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to implement this following buttons.Which library should i use for this?
[image]

Comment: You should use UIKit

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski UIKit is big isn't it?

Comment: You are looking for UIAlertController with style ".ActionSheet"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `UIKit` standard framework, using `UIAlertController` with `UIActionSheet` style will work for you

**Example Code**

```
let alertController:UIAlertController = UIAlertController.init(title: "Is this right!",message:"Bla Bla Bla?", preferredStyle:.actionSheet)
            alertController.view.tintColor = self.saveProfileButton.titleLabel?.tintColor

            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "No", style:.default, handler: { (alertAction) in
                 //here add your code to handle No action
            }))
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Yes", style:.default, handler: { (alertAction) in
                //here add your code to handle YES action
            }))
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style:.destructive, handler: nil))
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks for thy help

Comment: @user8615957 my answer was updated with some code example hope that helps you